# How to figure out Oracle Connection String from PL SQL Developer's connection?

Tags: connection-string, plsqldeveloper, dbvisualizer

I PL/SQL Developer installed (pre-loaded by my company) on my laptop, when I want to connect to an ORACLE database, all I give it is Database Name, User Name and Password and it connects successfully.

I also have DBVisualizer installed on my machine (I downloaded it because it like its ease of use) which when connecting to ORACLE wants to know SID or TNSNAMES or ORACLE Service name, none of which I know.

How can i figure those details out from my working PL SQL Development so that I can use my DBVisualizer to connect to the same ORACLE database

Thanks
Kay

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to figure it out myself. Under Help -> Support in PL SQL Developer, there is a tab called TNS Names that lists all the available ORACLE SIDs that are used in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Open a `cmd` prompt and type `tnsping dbname` (where `dbname` is whatever you are using for the 'database name' field in PL/SQL Developer, which may not be an actual database name).

SID is deprecated these days, and service names are preferred.

Note also that if your site uses LDAP, the name might not appear in TNSNAMES.ORA.